# Sorting numbers by rank PDO PHP

Tags: php, sorting, pdo, rank

so I'm trying to make a High-Scores system on php, but there's this really hard part that I can't figure out.

So the SQL database will have multiple players, each row will have 'playerName', 'defencelvl', 'defencexp', and others, but for testing purposes we could just try to rank them by who has the most defence experience.

Let's say there's three entries, it would look something like this

--NAME-- -LEVEL-  -EXP-

"Jordan", "92", "32,424,525"

"Tyler", "92", "32,892,241"

"Trent", "92", "32,492,641"

So the high-scores page would only be showing 1 player per search, something like view.php?username=Jordan, (I can figure out that stuff),
But the hard part that I can't seem to figure out is ranking them for what place they're in, so Jordan would be in 3rd place because his experience is lower then the others, Tyler would be in 1st place because his experience is the highest, and Trent would be in 2nd place, An almost exact example of what I'm doing is on this game website http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/compare?user1=S%A0U%A0O%A0M%A0I , That's the type of highscores I'm doing.

Again, I just can't figure out how to rank them, and I would like to do it for each skill without making too many PDO SQL querys. If you don't understand what I'm trying to say let me know and I'll post a more in depth description. Thanks!!

Comment: One value per cell. Your table shouldn't look like this in the first place.

Comment: You should be a bit more clear about what do you mean by ranking them. Do you mean getting the data in a specific order? do you mean how to show it on screen? do you mean how to write the sql query?. Plus, have you thought about the database structure? which tables are involved? what is the structure?

Comment: @user3238707 What I mean is, you have three CSV values in the one cell. Wouldn't it make more sense to put each value in it's own respective column? Then you can refer to them individually, and there'll be no need to parse out the values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a table with information similar to what you show, you only need a simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM `players`ORDER BY exp DESC
```

You can use 'desc' to reverse the order if you need/want to.

But as christopher mentions, you first should figure out what is going to be the dabatase structure and then you can do the queries. Don't worry about how many there are, if the DB is properly designed, there is not going to be any problem.

Comment: MY DB is very organized, if you'd like I could post the SQL portion with an example. What you showed me would organize it in the correct manner, but I wouldn't be able to compare the current players actual stat to the list of organized stats from the DESC function, and get the current players ranking.

Comment: what do you want to compare? the result of the query with what? the query I posted is just a very generic way to get the data from the table in ascending or descending order, but if you want a specific result, you may have to use other elements like LIMIT 1, it depends on what do you want to accomplish. I'm not clear with what you really want. can you rephrase your question, post some code or examples?